# Why am i getting a 404 js file, while including a script tag?

Tags: javascript, include, libraries

index.html

```
<head>
    <script src="/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/main.js
```

Structure

- Project

  - app.js
  - view

    - index.html
    - main.js

I've tried src="main.js". /view/main.js

Very basic, but dont want to get stuck on this any longer... sigh.

if it helps my app.js file has this:

`app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/view/home.html');
});`

Comment: Is main.js in the same directory as the html file you're accessing?

Comment: `/` refers to the root of the program. Have you tried `/view/main.js`? Are you using any special routing?

Comment: Also, make sure that the permissions on the file are correct

Comment: @MikeC updated, but yes i tried /view/main.js

Comment: From which directory you run your web server?

Comment: maybe `./main.js`?

Comment: @AnthonyRussell same directory, i am using node.js (learning).

Comment: / is the project/website root. try `<script src="./main.js"></script>`

Comment: @Tamango  from the base directory project, where my app.js is , the only routing i have is app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/view/home.html');
});

Comment: @mjw Tried that one, no lucky, i tried "main.js" "/main.js" "./main.js" i think im going crazy, or im forgetting to put a detail in my summary to resolve the error.

Comment: So, it seems that your server is only serving the 'home.html' file (or I think you meant 'index.html').
You need to serve whole directory.

Comment: @Tamango oh that makes sense, and wooops yea i meant index.html.

Comment: I don't see home.html in your project structure above. Where is it in the project?

Comment: @ThePirateBae , please add the code from your previous comments to the question, so new readers will clearly understand what was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, according to your comments - you are serving only the 'index.html' file instead of whole directory.
Try this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'view')));

//... other settings and server launching further
```

If you want to set serving static files to particular route - extend 'app.use' line with '/your-route', like this:

```
app.use('/your-route', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'view')));
```

After that you can use `<script src="main.js"></script>` in your index.html